# VB.Net: Positioning the Context Menu

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a custom button that displays a context menu and I managed to achieved this

[image]

but I want to do it like this

[image]

here is my code:

```
Private Sub Guna2ImageButton1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Guna2ImageButton1.MouseDown
        MetroContextMenu1.Show(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my problem solved, I have work around with the position itself.

I changed this `MetroContextMenu1.Show(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)`
to this `MetroContextMenu1.Show(Guna2ImageButton1, New System.Drawing.Point(-90, 20))`
and I achieved my desired result.